# Temperature sensors in android device

Tags: linux, architecture, temperature, sensors

I'm learning Linux architecture, and I became curious about hardware health monitoring which Linux supports.

So, most of the time it is temperature and voltage sensors.

When I open CPU-Z app, I can see in section `sensors`, various sensors, can someone describe me which temperature sensors represents, what component of hardware are these temperature sensors.

Like:

```
mtkswmt
mtkscpu
mtkspmic
mtksabb
mtksbattery
```

Or you can refer me to some book about those sensors which are used.

Answer (score 0):

mtkswmt MediaTek Sensor WMT
mtkscpu MediaTek Sensor CPU
mtkspmic MediaTek Sensor PMIC
mtksabb MediaTek Sensor ABB
mtksbattery MediaTek Sensor Battery
ref: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/mediatek/+/android-mtk-3.18/drivers/misc/mediatek/connectivity/common/combo/core/wmt_core.c